# docker login failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker-registry, bitbucket-pipelines, caddy

I have a Bitbucket pipeline where I try to connect to a private docker registry. Here is a command:

```
echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URI --username $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
```

which throws an error:

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URI/v2/
> failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable

But **this command works on my local PC** (I get "Login Succeeded" message).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You run that private registry on your own local network using that compose file?

Comment: @Erik I run it on DigitalOcean Droplet.

Comment: And when you test locally you do this against the repository running on DigitalOcean as well? Maybe locally you have some kind of direct SSH or VPN connection to the droplet that Bitbucket doesn't have?

Comment: @Erik I have no direct connection or vpn to my droplet. I connect to droplet with ```docker login``` with the same url, username and password.

Comment: Can you see in the proxy logs if the requests from the pipeline make it to the proxy at all? It would help if you can determine somehow which component specifically returns the 503 status code.

Comment: error message seems to hint that your `$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URI` is not expanded but rather used literally. can you check if variables are set correctly and you are properly escaping the command?

Comment: @timur I've made this variable not secured. Right now I can see the value of the variable and it is correct. But same error...

Comment: @timur It is strange, but I can't find any Bitbucket documentation which describes how to connect to a private self-hosted docker registry. Maybe custom registry url is not supported?

Comment: I don't think connectivity is the case. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/d70f6bb7923bd25e012fef006fcfde3881d31346/components/engine/registry/auth.go#L119) the error message you are getting should list actual URL - but it doesn't. I'd try to figure out why

Comment: @timur It was a secured variable so Bitbucket replaced it's value with it's name in logs (for security reason).

Comment: @timur My private docker registry domain is under cloudflare, may be that is a key to the problem, do you have any ideas? p.s. there is no firewall or 'i am under attack' mode

Comment: @timur cloudflare has blocked all requests from bitbucket, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare has blocked all requests from Bitbucket Pipeline. I've added IP ranges to whitelist. Everything is ok.